# Puppeteer - file chooser

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

File chooser doesn't work, I've tried puppeteer@2.0.0, but nothing, can u guys help work it out?

```
const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForFileChooser(),
  page.click('#mount_0_0 > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.rq0escxv.l9j0dhe7.du4w35lb > div:nth-child(5) > div > div > div.rq0escxv.l9j0dhe7.du4w35lb > div > div.iqfcb0g7.tojvnm2t.a6sixzi8.k5wvi7nf.q3lfd5jv.pk4s997a.bipmatt0.cebpdrjk.qowsmv63.owwhemhu.dp1hu0rb.dhp61c6y.l9j0dhe7.iyyx5f41.a8s20v7p > div > div > div > div > div.kr520xx4.pedkr2u6.ms05siws.pnx7fd3z.b7h9ocf4.pmk7jnqg.j9ispegn.k4urcfbm > div:nth-child(3) > div.n1l5q3vz.hv4rvrfc.dati1w0a > div.aov4n071 > div > div > div > div > div'),
])

await fileChooser.accept(['/example.png']);
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to upgrade puppeteer? Basically it is considered counter-productive to try to mend programs running older version of software - there could be bugs already fixed in later versions. The current puppeteer version is 5.x.

Comment: It works! So puppeteer all the time downloaded 2.1.1 version. I used 'npm install puppeteer@5.2.0', but I had error with chromium, so I created new folder and file and then I installed all over again. And it works, thanks!